# cant delete out hidden frame in userform

Tags: excel, vba

I have a frame, which housed 4 option buttons, but it got hidden once I moved it. Couldnt find it so I made a new frame to house those option buttons. I have resized my userform many times to try and find the frame, but nowhere to be found. I looked in the properties window and couldnt find it (`frame 20`), but I know it still exists with the buttons somewhere because I have code to go back and display a msgbox to show blank control fields and they keep popping up--even when they aren't on the page.

any ideas or do I need to scrap my whole form and start over?

The code, which displays a msgbox shows the controls that are still blank and need to fill out. the 4 opt buttons that are outlined in red are on frame 20, which doesn't exist in the form according to the properties menu

[image]

Comment: If its not listed in the forms properties window then it definitely does not exist on the form, something else is going on. What exactly makes you think its still there?

Comment: @AlexK. updated my post to show you what i mean

Comment: Seems like the frame is gone but the controls still exist?  Are they in the properties window? If so set their left/top props to 0, send any other controls to the back & you should see it

Comment: I still couldn't find them, but just added logic in my code to omit them from being added to the collection. not ideal workaround, but don't have the time to rebuild this. appreciate your input!